# cuda reduce parallel: how to design the grid size?

Tags: cuda

I am learning cuda parallel reduction, the code is:

```
__global__ void reduce0(int * input, int *output, int N)
{
    extern __shared__ int sdata[1024];


    //set thread ID
    unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int idx = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x * 2 + threadIdx.x;
    //boundary check
    if (tid >= N) return;

    unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    //convert global data pointer to the
    int *idata = input + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x * 2;
    if (idx + blockDim.x<N)
    {
        input[idx] += input[idx + blockDim.x];
    }
    __syncthreads();

    for (int stride = 1; stride < blockDim.x; stride *= 2)
    {
        if ((tid % (2 * stride)) == 0)
        {
            idata[tid] += idata[tid + stride];
        }
        //synchronize within block
        __syncthreads();
    }

    if (tid == 0)
    {
        output[blockIdx.x] = idata[0];
    }
}
```

In order to use this cuda function, the code is:

```
int blocksize = 1024;
dim3 block(blocksize);
dim3 grid(N / blocksize + 1);  // N is the size of array
reduce0<<<grid.x/2, block >>>(input, output, N);
```

The above code is correct.

My question is why the `reduce0` is used by `reduce0<<<grid.x/2, block>>>(input, output, N)`?

I have tried `reduce0<<<grid.x, block>>>(input, output, N)`, and the result is wrong.

The complete code is: https://github.com/zhang-qiang-github/Cuda_Reduce_Parallel

Comment: “The above code is correct” — it most certainly isn’t, but the division by two comes from the fact that each thread reduces two input values

Comment: I can understand that each thread reduces two input values resulting in the division by two. But, what I feel confuzed is that `reduce0<<<grid.x, block>>>(input, output, N)` will return the wrong result. In my understanding, more grid will still return the correct result.

Comment: In addition, you mean the above code is incorrect? What's wrong with the above code? I have tested the code for many times with cpu, and the return result is correct. I have published the code in github (https://github.com/zhang-qiang-github/Cuda_Reduce_Parallel).